# Cannot figure issue of "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" on Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, macos, compilation

I am trying to compile the following code on Xcode (it has been working perfectly fine on Linux and I am trying to generate Mac OS executables with no success):

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 

#endif                      

#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <tchar.h>

#endif
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#include "imgdec.h"
#include "imgmacro.h"
#include "tiffutils.h"
#ifndef WIN32
#include "internal.h"
#endif


#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define PI M_PI

int Image_border = 10;


int usage(prog)
char *prog;
{
  static char *helpmsg[] = {
    "Function: Canny edge detection (undebugged)\n",
    "Options:\n",
    "  -s (float): standard deviation for Gaussian kernel [Default: 1.0] \
    -t threshold [0 to 255]\n",
    NULL
  };
  char **p=helpmsg;

  fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s {Options first} infile outfile\n",prog);
  while (*p)
    (void) fputs(*p++,stderr);
  return(-1);
}

int write_t1image(filename,image, ti, threshold)
char *filename;
FIMAGE image;
IMAGE *ti; // just need the header 
float threshold;
{
  //FILE *stream;
  int filetype();
  IMAGE *tiffimage;
  unsigned char *ptr;
  unsigned char val;
  short sval;

   int x, y, yy;
  fprintf(stderr,"image depth,etc. %d %d %d %d\n",
                (int) ImageBPL(ti),ImageDepth(ti),image.w,image.h);

   tiffimage  = MakeImage(
                          ImageBPL(ti), 
                          ImageDepth(ti),
                          image.w,
                          image.h,
                          ImageXRes(ti), // original resolution 
                          ImageYRes(ti),
                          ImageResUnit(ti), //imageresunit
                          ImagePhoto(ti) // photo interp 
                        );
   if( !tiffimage) 
   { 
       fprintf(stderr,"write_timage(): null tiff image.\n");
       return (int) NULL;
   }

    for( y = 0, ptr = ImagePtr(tiffimage), yy = 0; y < image.h; ++y, ++yy )
           for( x = 0; x < image.w; ++x )
           {   sval = (short)nint(image.ptr[y][x]);
                val = (byte) BETWEEN(sval,0,255);
                if (val > threshold)
                    ptr[x + y*image.w] = 255;
                else ptr[x + y*image.w] = 0;
           }





   WriteImageToTiff( filename, tiffimage );

   return 0;
}

/*
void canny_edge_detect(char *grey_filename,char *edge_filename,float sigma)
{
   char *c;
   char *in, *out;
   FIMAGE image,edge,grad,angle;
//   float sigma=1.0;
   float threshold = -1.0; // no threshold 
   IMAGE *tiffimage;
   Image_border = (int)2*(sigma + 4);   // > 1/2 Gaussian kernel size 
 // here is where it differs from original canny by replacing read_tiffimage with
   // the generic reader of QBIC 
   if ((tiffimage = read_timage(grey_filename,&image)) == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr,"couldn't open file %s\n",grey_filename);
     exit(-1);
   }

   edge.w = grad.w = angle.w = image.w;   edge.h = grad.h = angle.h = image.h;
   alloc_fimage(&edge);   alloc_fimage(&grad);   alloc_fimage(&angle);
   gaussfilt(image,sigma);
   gradient(image,grad,angle);
   non_maximum_suppression(edge,grad,angle);
   fprintf(stderr, "writing image out with threshold: %d\n",threshold);
   write_t1image(edge_filename,edge, tiffimage, threshold); 
}
*/




int
non_maximum_suppression(edge,grad,angle)
FIMAGE edge,grad,angle;
{
   register float **e=edge.ptr,**g=grad.ptr,**a=angle.ptr;
   int i,j,w=edge.w,h=edge.h;
   float theta,alpha,G1,G2;

   reflect(grad,1,1);
   for (j=0; j < h; j++)
     for (i=0; i < w; i++) {
       theta = a[j][i];
       alpha = ABS(tan(theta));
       e[j][i] = 0.0;
       if (theta <= -PI/4) {                /* use lower + lower right */
         alpha = 1/alpha;
         G1 = g[j-1][i] + alpha*(g[j-1][i+1] - g[j-1][i]);
         if (g[j][i] < G1)
           continue;
         G2 = g[j+1][i] + alpha*(g[j+1][i-1] - g[j+1][i]);
         if (g[j][i] < G2)
           continue;
         e[j][i] = g[j][i];     /* edge point with its strength */
       } else if (theta > -PI/4 && theta <= 0.0) {  /* use right + lower right */
         G1 = g[j][i+1] + alpha*(g[j-1][i+1] - g[j][i+1]);
         if (g[j][i] < G1)
           continue;
         G2 = g[j][i-1] + alpha*(g[j+1][i-1] - g[j][i-1]);
         if (g[j][i] < G2)
           continue;
         e[j][i] = g[j][i];     /* edge point with its strength */
       } else if (theta > 0.0 && theta <= PI/4) {   /* use right + upper right */
         G1 = g[j][i+1] + alpha*(g[j+1][i+1] - g[j][i+1]);
         if (g[j][i] < G1)
           continue;
         G2 = g[j][i-1] + alpha*(g[j-1][i-1] - g[j][i-1]);
         if (g[j][i] < G2)
           continue;
         e[j][i] = g[j][i];     /* edge point with its strength */
       } else if (theta > PI/4) {          /* use upper + upper right */
         alpha = 1/alpha;
         G1 = g[j+1][i] + alpha*(g[j+1][i+1] - g[j+1][i]);
         if (g[j][i] < G1)
           continue;
         G2 = g[j-1][i] + alpha*(g[j-1][i-1] - g[j-1][i]);
         if (g[j][i] < G2)
           continue;
         e[j][i] = g[j][i];     /* edge point with its strength */
       } 
     }
   return 0;
}

int
gradient(image,grad,angle)
FIMAGE image,grad,angle;
{
   register float **p=image.ptr,**g=grad.ptr,**a=angle.ptr;
   int i,j,w=image.w,h=image.h;
   float dx,dy;

   reflect(image,1,1);
   for (j=0; j < h; j++)
     for (i=0; i < w; i++) {
       dx = (p[j][i+1] - p[j][i-1])/2.0;
       dy = (p[j+1][i] - p[j-1][i])/2.0;
       g[j][i] = hypot(dx,dy);
       if (dx != 0.0)
         a[j][i] = atan(dy/dx);
       else if (dy != 0)
         a[j][i] = SIGN(PI/2,dy);
       else
         a[j][i] = 0.0;
     }
   return 0;
}

#if 0

void
matherr(struct _exception *exc)
{
   fprintf(stderr,"%s: ",exc->name);
   switch (exc->type) {
     case DOMAIN:
       fprintf(stderr,"argument domain exception\n");
       break;
     case SING:
       fprintf(stderr,"argument singularity\n");
       break;
     case OVERFLOW:
       fprintf(stderr,"Overflow range exception\n");
       break;
     case UNDERFLOW:
       fprintf(stderr,"Underflow range exception\n");
       break;
     default:
       fprintf(stderr,"Unknown Exception\n");
   }
   fprintf(stderr,"\tinput arguments: %f\t%f\n",exc->arg1,exc->arg2);
   fprintf(stderr,"\treturn Value: %f\n",exc->retval);
   return(0);
}

#endif

void
get_gauss_kernel(gf,sigma)
register FILTER *gf;
float sigma;
{
   double sum,h,den=2*sigma*sigma;
   register int j;

   for (j=1,sum=1.0; (h=exp(-j*j/den)) > 0.001; j++) {
     sum += 2*h;
   }
   gf->taps = 2*j + 1;
   gf->k = (float *) malloc(gf->taps*sizeof(*(gf->k)));
   gf->k += (gf->taps-1)/2;
   for (j=0; j <= gf->taps/2; j++)
     gf->k[j] = gf->k[-j] = exp(-j*j/den)/sum;
   printf("Number of taps =%d\n",gf->taps);
   for (j=0; j <= gf->taps/2; j++)
     printf("g[%d] = %f\n",j,gf->k[j]);

}

int
gaussfilt(image, sigma)
FIMAGE image;
float sigma;
{
   FILTER gf;
   FIMAGE scr;

   get_gauss_kernel(&gf,sigma);
   scr.w = image.w;  scr.h = image.h;  alloc_fimage(&scr);
   hor_reflect(image,gf.taps/2,1);
   hor_sym_filter(image,scr,gf);
   ver_reflect(scr,gf.taps/2,1);
   ver_sym_filter(scr,image,gf);
   free_fimage(scr);
   free((gf.k-(gf.taps-1)/2));
   return 0;
}

// use this for stand alone version that writes files out 
#ifdef WIN32
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
#else
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
{
   char *c,*prog=argv[0];
   //char *in, *out;
   FIMAGE image,edge,grad,angle;
   float sigma=1.0;
   float threshold = -1.0; // no threshold 
   IMAGE *tiffimage;


   while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-')
     for (c = argv[0]+1; *c != '\0'; c++)
       switch (*c) {
         case 's':
           --argc; sigma = (float) atof(*++argv);
           {
               printf ("sigma being set to %f\n", sigma);
           }
           break;
         case 't':
           --argc; threshold = (float) atof(*++argv);

             if( threshold < 0 || threshold > 255 )
             {
                 usage(prog); 
                 return -1; // exit 
             }
             printf("thresold: %f\n",threshold);
             break;
         default:
           fprintf(stderr,"%s: illegal option %c\n",prog,*c);
         case 'h':
           usage(prog);
           break;
       }
   if (argc < 2)
     usage(prog);

   Image_border = (int)2*(sigma + 4);   // > 1/2 Gaussian kernel size 
 // here is where it differs from original canny by replacing read_tiffimage with
  //  the generic reader of QBIC 
   if ((tiffimage = read_timage(*argv,&image)) == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr,"%s: couldn't open file %s\n",prog,*(argv+1));
     exit(-1);
   }

   edge.w = grad.w = angle.w = image.w;   edge.h = grad.h = angle.h = image.h;
   alloc_fimage(&edge);   alloc_fimage(&grad);   alloc_fimage(&angle);
   gaussfilt(image, sigma);
   gradient(image,grad,angle);
   non_maximum_suppression(edge,grad,angle);
   fprintf(stderr, "writing image out with threshold: %f\n",threshold);
   write_t1image(*++argv,edge, tiffimage, threshold);

   return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile, I get the following errors (8 errors):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TIFFClose", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
      _WriteImageToTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFGetField", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFOpen", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
      _WriteImageToTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFReadScanline", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFScanlineSize", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFSetField", referenced from:
      _WriteImageToTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFWriteScanline", referenced from:
      _WriteImageToTiff in tiffutils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Also, here is my tiffutils.c code (not sure if this is related or not):

```
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include "tiffwrap.h"


void free(void *ptr);

static unsigned char MASK[8] = {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};

IMAGE *GetImageFromTiff(char *filename)
{

   IMAGE *iptr;
   TIFF *tif;
   ttag_t imagelength,imagewidth;
   unsigned char *buf;
   unsigned int sample=0;
   float imagexres,imageyres;
   unsigned short imageresunit,photointerp, imagedepth;
   long row,size;
   int bpl;

   iptr = (IMAGE *) malloc(sizeof(IMAGE));

   tif = TIFFOpen(filename, "r");
   TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &imagelength);
   bpl= TIFFScanlineSize(tif); 
   bpl= 4*( (bpl+3)/4) ;
   size=imagelength*bpl;
   buf = (unsigned char *) calloc(size,1);
   for (row = 0; row < imagelength; row++)
      TIFFReadScanline(tif, buf+row*bpl, row, sample);

   iptr->bpl = bpl;
   iptr->pbuf = buf;
   if (TIFFGetField(tif,TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, &photointerp))
      iptr->photo = photointerp;
   else
      iptr->photo = UNDEFINED;
   if( TIFFGetField(tif,TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, &imagexres) )
      iptr->xres = imagexres;
   else
      iptr->xres = UNDEFINED;
   if ( TIFFGetField(tif,TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, &imageyres) )
      iptr->yres = imageyres;
   else
      iptr->yres = UNDEFINED;
   if(TIFFGetField(tif,TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT, &imageresunit))
      iptr->resunit = imageresunit;
   else
      iptr->resunit = UNDEFINED;
   TIFFGetField(tif,TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &imagewidth);
   iptr->width = imagewidth;
   TIFFGetField(tif,TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, &imagedepth);
   iptr->depth = imagedepth;
   iptr->length = imagelength;


   TIFFClose(tif);
   return iptr;
}







int WriteImageToTiff(char *filename, IMAGE *pimage)
{
   TIFF *tif;
   //   char *buf;
   long row;
   //   int bpl;

   unsigned int sample=0;


   tif = TIFFOpen(filename, "w");
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, pimage->width);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH,pimage->length);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE,pimage->depth);
   //TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_LZW);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_NONE);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG,PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
   if(pimage->xres != UNDEFINED)
      TIFFSetField(tif,TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, pimage->xres);
   if(pimage->yres != UNDEFINED)
      TIFFSetField(tif,TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, pimage->yres);
   if(pimage->resunit != UNDEFINED)
      TIFFSetField(tif,TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT, pimage->resunit);
   if(pimage->photo != UNDEFINED)
      TIFFSetField(tif,TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, pimage->photo);
   for(row=0; row<pimage->length; ++row)
           TIFFWriteScanline(tif, pimage->pbuf+row*pimage->bpl, row, sample);

           TIFFClose(tif);
    return 1;
}


IMAGE *MakeImage(
                        unsigned long bpl,
                        unsigned short imagedepth,
                        unsigned long imagewidth,
                        unsigned long imagelength,
                        float imagexres,
                        float imageyres,
                        unsigned short imageresunit,
                        unsigned short photointerp
                        )
{
   IMAGE *iptr;
   unsigned char *buf;
   long size;

   iptr = (IMAGE *) malloc(sizeof(IMAGE));

   size=imagelength*bpl;
   buf = (unsigned char *) calloc(size,1);

   iptr->bpl = bpl;
   iptr->pbuf = buf;
   iptr->photo = photointerp;
   iptr->xres = imagexres;
   iptr->yres = imageyres;
   iptr->resunit = imageresunit;
   iptr->width = imagewidth;
   iptr->depth = imagedepth;
   iptr->length = imagelength;
   return iptr;
}

int close_image(IMAGE *pimage)
{
   free((char *)pimage->pbuf);
   free((char *)pimage);
   return 0;
}
/* x is column y is row */
int GetPixel( int x, int y, IMAGE *I ) /* binary only */
     {  int bpl;
        unsigned char val;

        /*clip*/
        if( x < 0 || y < 0   
                  || x >= ImageWidth(I)
                  || y >= ImageLength(I) ) return 0; /* white */

         bpl = ImageBPL(I); /*bytes per line*/
         val = I->pbuf[y*bpl + x/8];
         return  (MASK[x % 8] & val)>0?1:0;

     }

void PutPixel(int x, int y, unsigned char p, IMAGE *I )
    {
        int bpl, spot;
         unsigned char val;
        /*clip*/
    //   if (p == 1)
    //   fprintf(stderr,"in put pixel %d %d %d\n",x,y,p);
        if( x < 0 || y < 0   
                  || x >= ImageWidth(I)
                  || y >= ImageLength(I) ) return; 

         bpl = ImageBPL(I); /*bytes per line*/
         spot = y*bpl + x/8;
         val = ((I->pbuf[spot] & MASK[x % 8])>0)?1:0;
                 p = (p > 0)? 1:0;

          if( p  != val ) 
              I->pbuf[spot] =  I->pbuf[spot] | MASK[x % 8] ;
        //  if (p ==1)
         // fprintf(stderr,"after put pixel val and p %d %d %d\n",val,p,I->pbuf[spot]); 


     }

int 
readtif ( image, rows, cols, hdr, file )
    unsigned char *image;
    int     *rows, *cols;
    IMAGE   **hdr;
    char    *file;
{

    IMAGE *Image;
    int width, height, bpl, depth;
    int x, y;


    /* get image attributes */

    Image = GetImageFromTiff(file);
    width = ImageWidth(Image);
    height = ImageLength(Image);
    bpl = ImageBPL(Image);
    depth = ImageDepth(Image); 

    if (depth == 1) {   /* binary image */

    /* the TIFF convention is to represent white by 1 and black by 0 */

    for( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
        for( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        *(image ++) = (GetPixel(x,y,Image) == 0 ? 1 : 0);

    }
    else if (depth == 8) {  /* gray-level image */

    for( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
              for( x = 0; x < width; x++ ) 
               *( image + y*width + x) =   *(ImagePtr(Image) + y* ImageBPL (Image) + x);
        /*
        memcpy (image + y*width, 
            ImagePtr(Image) + y* ImageBPL (Image), width);
         */

    }
    else {
    fprintf (stderr, "readtif: sorry, non-standard depth\n");
    return -1;
    }

    *rows = height;
    *cols = width;
    *hdr = Image;

    return depth;
}


int 
writetif ( image, rows, cols, hdr, file, bgcolor, fgcolor )
    unsigned char *image;
    int     rows, cols;
    IMAGE   *hdr;
    char    *file;
    int     bgcolor, fgcolor;
{

    IMAGE *Out;
    unsigned char   *iptr;
    int width, height, depth;
    int x, y;


    /* set image attributes */

    width = cols;
    height = rows;
    depth = 1; 

    Out = MakeImage ((long) ImageBPL(hdr), (short) depth, (long) width, 
             (long) height, ImageXRes(hdr), ImageYRes(hdr), 
             (unsigned short) ImageResUnit(hdr), (short) ImagePhoto(hdr));

    /* the TIFF convention is to represent white by 1 and black by 0 */

    iptr = image;

    for( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    for( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        PutPixel(x,y, (*iptr++ == bgcolor ? 1 : 0), Out);

    WriteImageToTiff( file, Out );

    return 1;
}
```

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: Also, maybe I should mention that (since a similar question has been asked before), I cannot find those _TIFF libraries to add onto my project through the Build Phases tab. Any other ideas will be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can remove all the code, it won't help here. You're missing a library (or at least one for the target you try to create code for: `x86_64`). Did you try creating `ia32` code instead?

Comment: Also, the command doing the final linking step that works fine on your linux box might give some hints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ Felix Palmen. So when you say create ia32, do you mean to change the architectures to i386, or to change the CPPFLAGS on the Makefile from -m64 to -m32? Or both?

Comment: well these should match, but I don't know *Xcode* sorry -- I *guess* both.

Comment: So you have the TIFF library and have set the target to link it in?  If so you need to check the CPU architectures supported by this library using the `file` command from the command line.

Comment: @trojanfoe, under the target section on Xcode->Build Settings->Search Paths, I have added the TIFF library into Library Search Paths, if this is what you meant.

When I type file on the command line, this is what I get:

    Usage: file [-bchikLNnprsvz0] [-e test] [-f namefile] [-F separator] [-m magicfiles] [-M magicfiles] file...
       file -C -m magicfiles

But I am not sure what it means..?

Comment: Yeah, you have to type `file <libfile.a>`.